# sql command to look for every single char typed

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using SQlite and have the following table:

[image]

What I want to do is for example if the user searchs "afm" is to return the 1th 3rd and 4th row. Is there any way to do it with only one statement or operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`instr()`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr) to test whether one string appears within another:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE instr("afm", myChar)>0;
```